# How to edit controller in laravel to redirect user to a page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paytm

I have created paytm integration with my website using a user made *package* for paytm(*anand siddharth package*).
my `ordercontroller` is below:

```html
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use PaytmWallet;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EventRegistration;


class OrderController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Payment Gateway.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register()
    {
        return view('payment');
    }


    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Payment Gateway.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function order(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'mobile_no' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);


        $input = $request->all();
        $input['order_id'] = $request->mobile_no.rand(1,100);
        $input['fee'] = 50;


        EventRegistration::create($input);


        $payment = PaytmWallet::with('receive');
        $payment->prepare([
          'order' => $input['order_id'],
          'user' => 'your paytm user',
          'mobile_number' => 'your paytm number',
          'email' => 'your paytm email',
          'amount' => $input['fee'],
          'callback_url' => url('api/payment/status')
        ]);
        return $payment->receive();
    }


    /**
     * Obtain the payment information.
     *
     * @return Object
     */
    public function paymentCallback()
    {
        $transaction = PaytmWallet::with('receive');


        $response = $transaction->response();
        $order_id = $transaction->getOrderId();


        if($transaction->isSuccessful()){
          EventRegistration::where('order_id',$order_id)->update(['status'=>2, 'transaction_id'=>$transaction->getTransactionId()]);


          dd('Payment Successfully Paid.');
        }else if($transaction->isFailed()){
          EventRegistration::where('order_id',$order_id)->update(['status'=>1, 'transaction_id'=>$transaction->getTransactionId()]);
          dd('Payment Failed.');
        }
    }
}
```

i know the call back url is for redirecting after the payment is done. but how do i edit this `ordercontroller` in order to get redirected to paytm merchant page to make the user do the payment?

Comment: Did you try `return redirect('http://payment_page')` ?

Comment: i mean am using paytm payment gateway.i ve done evrythng as they said but when i click the submit button,its says "redirecting you to merchant page" but it redirects me to localhost/payment/api/status. paytm gives us something like call back url. do you know where to place the call back url

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it looks like the tutorial you have been following to get this far:

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/paytm-payment-gateway-integration-example-in-laravel-5example.html

If this is the case, then simply navigating your browser to `http://yoursite.com/event-registration` would display the **register.php** file (which is actually the payment view) mentioned at the very end of the tutorial. Note that this file contains a `POST` HTML Form, which when submitted sends the User to `http://yoursite.com/payment` which will initiate the `OrderController@order` method.

### Edit

Referring to the title of the question - if you want to redirect a user to another Route, from inside a Controller, then check out the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects

In short, using `return redirect('route/path')` will achieve this.

Comment: i mean am using paytm payment gateway.i ve done evrythng as they said but when i click the submit button,its says "redirecting you to merchant page" but it redirects me to localhost/payment/api/status. paytm gives us something like call back url. do you know where to place the call back url

Comment: Inside the `order()` method you have this line: `'callback_url' => url('api/payment/status')`

Comment: but is that for redirecting the user after the payment is done?

Comment: That line redirects the user to the `Route::post('payment/status', 'OrderController@paymentCallback');` route after payment. Which calls the `paymentCallback()` method. See where it says `if($transaction->isSuccessful()` and replace `dd('Payment Successfully Paid.');` with `return redirect('path/to/go/to')`

Comment: ok so that 'callback_url' => url('api/payment/status') is used for redirecting user after payment. but how can i send the user to merchant page.

Comment: is there any way like adding parameters inside this'callback_url' => url('api/payment/status') such that first the user is taken to merchant page and then after payment to my custom page